# Astro Dynamic Import || An error occurred. Unexpected "nst"

Tags: astrojs, dynamic-import

I try dynamic import component:

```
const Content = (await import(`../../components/${config.template}/Content/Content.astro`)).default;
```

everytime i get:

```
An error occurred.
Unexpected "nst"
```

harcoded data working correct:

```
import Content from "../../components/minimal/Content/Content.astro";
```

I try very very different ways but not working, i spend few hrs and always isssue with dynamic imports.

Can anyone give any tips?